# Windows is ignoring JAVA_HOME or PATH for java

Tags: windows-7

Yeah, as title says, no matter what i do, Windows is refusing to change the path away from the 1.8 JRE.

The error started happening becouse i moved the JRE folder away to try and see if it would change, but it doesnt.

[Folder layout](https://puu.sh/EdItx/808d5852e2.png)

[Error](https://puu.sh/EdIx7/7800d00345.png)

My path only points to the 1.12.0.2 JDK, so i'm not sure what is going on...

Comment: Your screenshots are inaccessible.  Please upload the screenshots using the built-in functionality of this website.  As you are doing that provide the contents for your system variables (user and system).

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is an environment variable. You do not only need to change the `JAVA_HOME` but also the `PATH`. Be that you can specify the `PATH` as `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to eliminate multiple changes. You need to also keep in mind that if you change environment variables you need to refresh/open new cmd to show the changes

Comment: When entering an executable at the command prompt, the command prompt uses  PATH  to find the EXE. The command prompt won't use JAVA_HOME  It looks like JAVA_HOME is as a convenience, maybe used by some programs or by you https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was using the PowerShell **Get-Command java** line.

The results indicated there were mulltiple java.exe files on my system, which are added by default by Java, when it's installed. Deleting the other 2 from the PATH variable fixed my problem.

[image]

Comment: Also bear in mind that you didn't even show your PATH variable in your question. Ideal to see what's happening might've been to show PATH preferably before and after